# return a value from class python

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

---

**Edit**

So I asked this question earlier and I received some good insight, but I feel like my question wasn't really answered. I'm building a small program to practice with python and making GUI's and I'm having a small problem with a button command.

```
#This is the temperature menu:
def temperM(self, *args):
    self.clearscreen(self.frame)
    self.frame2 = Frame(self.root)
    self.frame2.grid(column = 0, row = 0)


    self.firstunit = StringVar()
    self.secondunit = StringVar()

    self.entryspace = IntVar()
    self.displayspace = IntVar()

    #Create back button

    #This is the part that needs to be fixed

    self.back = Button(self.frame2, text = "< Back",
     command = lambda: self.redo(self.frame2))
    self.back.grid(column = 1, row = 3)

    self.label = Label(self.frame2, text = "Convert from: ")
    self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = 4)

    #Create the check boxes

    self.celsius = Checkbutton(self.frame2, text = "Celsius",
     variable = self.firstunit, onvalue = 'celsius')
    self.celsius.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

    self.fahrenheit = Checkbutton(self.frame2, text = "Fahrenheit",
     variable = self.secondunit, onvalue = 'fahrenheit')
    self.fahrenheit.grid(column = 3, row = 2)

    #Create entry space to recieve text


    #This is where the problem starts.
    self.entry = Entry(self.frame2, width = 7,
     textvariable = self.entryspace)
    self.entry.grid(column = 3, row = 3)

    self.compute = Calculate(self.entryspace.get())

    self.button = Button(self.frame2, text = "Calculate",
     command = lambda: self.displayspace.set(self.compute.celtoFah()))
    self.button.grid(column = 3, row = 4)

    self.display = Label(self.frame2, textvariable = self.displayspace)
    self.display.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
```

I have this function inside of a `class Menu` with `def__init__(self, root)` which creates all the different menu options.

```
class Calculate:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def celtoFah(self):
        try:
            self.temp = Temperature()
            self.number = float(self.number)
            return self.temp.C2F(self.number)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

And I have this class which holds all the different calculations that will be used in the code.

What I'm having trouble with is with my button command `command = lambda: self.displayspace.set(self.compute.celtoFah())`. When I run the code and press 'Calculate' which runs the command, `self.displayspace.set()`, it doesn't set `self.displayspace` to what I believe the returned value should be. Instead it returns and sets `self.displayspace` to what `self.entryspace.get()` is originally without modifications which is 32 and 0 respectively, which causes me to believe that the line `self.compute = Calulate(self.entryspace.get())` is not updating when I put in a new value so `self.entryspace` is not getting a new value but its retaining the same initial value established by `IntVar()`. Am I doing something wrong in my code for `self.entryspace` not to be updating with a new value? At first I had it as a `StringVar()` which would convert to a float in `celtoFah` but I was throwing ValueError because it was receiving an empty string even after a user inputs a value. I really want to keep all calculations in a separate class since I will be having 20+ in the final version, but should I move these commands into `class Menu` or is there another I can do this by having a separate class? If you need to see my full code here is a link to it on github: https://github.com/Flameancer/Unit-Conversion-Program-in-Python

Comment: As a side note, this looks like Python 2.x (from the capitalized `Tkinter`). In Python 2.x, you should always define new-style classes: `class Bar(object):`, not `class Bar:`.

Comment: Posting your actual code wouldn't help—but posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would. That is, a complete but stripped-down example that demonstrates your problem, and can be run, and has real names instead of "foo" and "something", and doesn't have all this extraneous code that's irrelevant to the problem. (Does Tkinter or ttk really have anything to do with your question? Wouldn't it be exactly the same question without it?)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't pass values between *classes*, but between *instances* of those classes. At any given time, you may have 0, 1, or 30 different `Foo` instances; how does a `Bar` instance even know which one you want?

The first question is, who's calling that `something` method on that `Bar`? Whoever it is, he has the value. Maybe it should be the `Foo` instance that's doing the calling.

For that to happen, the `foo` instance has to know about a `bar` instance. Maybe you want to create one in the constructor:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, argument):
        # ...
        self.bar = Bar(42)
        # ...
```

… and now you can use it the same way as any other member:

```
    def function(self, *args):
        # ...
        randomness = self.bar.something()
        self.displayfield.set(randomness)
        # ...
```

Or maybe you're already constructing one somewhere, and you just want to pass it to the `Foo` instance as a constructor:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, argument, bar):
        # ...
        self.bar = bar
        # ...

bar = Bar(42)
foo = Foo(23, bar)
```

Or maybe you want to construct a new one locally each time you call the `function` method. Or maybe you want a global `Bar` instance shared by everyone, no matter how many `Foo` instances you have. Or…

As you can see, there are many different possible relationships between a `Foo` instance and a `Bar` instance, and which one is appropriate depends entirely on what `Foo` and `Bar` actually represent. This is the code idea behind object modeling: there are things of some kind that your objects represent, and the relationships between those things are reflected in the relationships between those objects.

Comment: Ok, thats very insightful, but I'm still have the same problem. Here is my actual code. [link](https://github.com/Flameancer/Unit-Conversion-Program-in-Python.git) This should help alot with my problem